# Exodus 40 difference between "thou" and "he", and the official position of Moses

Tags: grammar, exodus, kjv

My questions are in Exodus 40, from verses 2-15 the word "thou" is used and from verses 19-30 the word "he" is used is there a important distinction? Also, Moses seems to be allowed access into the tabernacle what official position does he hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is actually quite simple.

In Ex 40:1-15 records a series of direct instruction by God to Moses; Moses is consistently addressed as "you" (or "thou in the KJV).

In Ex 40:18-33 records Moses actually doing and carrying out the instructions of God - the whole being a simple narrative and thus Moses is referred to as "he".

In simplified terms - Moses was told to do something and he did it.

Moses' official position was human leader and prophet of Israel.